# React app keep crashing on heroku / node.js

Tags: reactjs, heroku

2020-07-21T14:16:10.473788+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=reacthelloworld.herokuapp.com request_id=e53b2e2b-48a5-4251-844a-ebb4c202cad7 fwd="65.92.155.165" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-07-21T14:16:13.905886+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=reacthelloworld.herokuapp.com request_id=6a6143e4-0d01-4127-981e-b1652f909441 fwd="65.92.155.165" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

```
     npm install -g serve
     serve -s build
   
   Find out more about deployment here:
   
     bit.ly/CRA-deploy
```

-----> Caching build
- node_modules

-----> Pruning devDependencies
audited 1646 packages in 12.038s

```
   62 packages are looking for funding
     run `npm fund` for details
   
   found 1 low severity vulnerability
     run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

- Build succeeded!
  -- Discovering process types
  Procfile declares types     -> (none)
  Default types for buildpack -> web
- Compressing...
  Done: 59.7M
  -- Launching...
  Released v3
  https://reacthelloworld.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

I know it could be few things all over but I think heroku is not recognizing the path, I did deployed apps before but had to change the computer and re install node all over, at this point need an advice please

Comment: Hi Vania! 

Please go over https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try asking the question again.

Comment: sorry Andres, just really frustrated at this point, I know it is a small mistake but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to host your React app on Heroku.
If that's the case, you can build React locally and upload static files to Heroku ([this](https://gist.github.com/wh1tney/2ad13aa5fbdd83f6a489) can help).
Or if you are trying to host your Node.js app which has React frontend, you should build the React app first and upload the Node.js app with it to Heroku. Heroku provides Node.js environment.

EDIT:
It turns out that `npm`/`yarn` was the issue.
Using `yarn` resolves the error.

Comment: yes, I am trying to host react on heroku , I did build locally, using static files, the app was a success deploying but gives me error when trying to open, the err is favicon.ico path not found H10, and heroku says something like it might be a time the app uploads...